# how do I correctly export a blender textured model into unity?

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, unity, blenderkit

I am trying to export a model from belnder to be used in unity. I followed this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yloupOUjMOA) which seems pretty useful but the textures are not showing up in unity correctly. I like the strategy in the video because ideally I can create whatever materials I want using blender nodes. Then only at the last step do I have to worry that they will work in unity. Otherwise you are limited to just using texture images for all assets and no other node types.

I have a simple blender unit cube with a brick material imported using belender kit. The belnder kit material uses many node types that wouldnt normally import into unity such as noise. I used the technique in the linked video to bake a texture image which allows me to delete all the material nodes and just use the baked texture as image texture with a principled bsdf, all of which should be supported by unity. When its all done it looks identical to the model when it was using the blender kit material. I export as fbx and import the model and image into unity. See screenshot below on the results:

[image]

After importing to unity as asset along with the texture image I get the below results. Note that the grey cube is a unit cube in unity for reference. Size of the imported model is correct but the texture is not mapped correctly. The texture is also not scaled correctly - in blender there are 4 rows of bricks and in unity there are 3 rows of bricks.

[image]

Is this an issue in how I'm exporting the fbx or how I'm importing it in unity?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: thanks for the reply! The link looks like its related to unreal engine not importing textures. Im talking about unity not unreal engine. I know I have to manually copy the texture to the unity asset folder where I copy the fbx. Totally fine with that and you can see in my screenshot the texture is there. Its just mapping the uv coordinates incorrectly. Trying to fix that.